# How can I find videos without country restrictions using Youtube's search API?

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to use Youtube's seach API to find videos that are available worldwide and not restricted to a country.

The [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#restrictionsp) has a `restriction` parameter, but this can only be used to restrict searches to a single country, for instance

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football&restriction=US
```

One possible solution would be adding multiple parameter values for all countries, but this is not supported by the API.

I could perform multiple searches for each country and combine the results, but this approach seems too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `&safeSearch=strict` to your query (for this to work you'll need to use version 2 of the api)

also check out [Fields](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial#Fields_Formatting_Rules) to further filter the restrictions

Comment: `&safeSearch=strict`doesn't seem to have effect on country restrictions. 
However, I think I managed to use the fields to filter on any results that have a `media:restriction` property.
I used `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=that's+amore+dean+martin&v=2&fields=openSearch:*,entry[not(media:group/media:restriction)]`

Comment: safeSearch doesn't filter over all of the restrictions indeed, but it should have an effect. GG on your success!

Comment: @dmonsieur Unfortunately, your suggested filter does not work with the new version 3 anymore. Does anybody know of an alternative?